# IBM MobileFirst Platform - Calling SOAP webservice from jquery with cross domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, soap, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an app using IBM Mobile First Platform 7.0.0 for android platform.

In this app, I need to call a SOAP web service. As we know, we have **adapters** for calling the SOAP service. But my requirement is to call the soap service from jquery and it is cross domain.

I googled and found some solution for calling the service. Code is below:

```
var wsUrl = "http://ipadd:port/example.asmx";
        var soapRequest = '<soap:Envelope> .....</soap:Envelope>';
        alert(soapRequest);
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: wsUrl,
            jsonpCallback: "MyCallbackDED",
            dataType: "xml",
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/example");
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
            },
            crossOrigin: true,
            data: soapRequest,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("suc: " + msg.tradeLicenseData.master[0].arabicAddress + ": " + msg.tradeLicenseData.master[0].arabicAddress);

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
            }

        });
```

The error i am getting is:-

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmqG55tt2d2FcT_WQ3WjCSKmtyFpkOcdpr…PersonalInformation%3E%3C/soap:Body%3E%3C/soap:Envelope%3E&_=1435644200261'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a relationship between your sample code and the error you are getting.

What I understand from the error you see is that you are trying to include a remote JavaScript file in your page, but that file does not have a MIME type of JavaScript.